# Prevent most users from logging in via non-SSO methods

Tags: single-sign-on

I would like to block all of our users from logging in except via SSO. However, I still have some cases where only I need to login with un:pw. Is it possible to allow me to bypass the blocked login? salesforce.com/?login=1 is confirmed to not work

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below steps given on Link https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_enforce_sso_login.htm&type=5

For a quick reference

[image: SSO Settings]

**For the users where you need to Bypass just create a new profile for** which Backdoor entry is required and do not enable the SSO Enabled permission as mentioned in step **3) c.** and give the My Domain URL to user to login using Salesforce Username and Password.