# Will Salesforce passwords still expire during SSO usage?

Tags: single-sign-on

We just implemented SSO in our SF environment with AD Azure being the identity provider. Therefore, we are no longer using the Salesforce passwords for our users.

Do we now need to enable "Password Never Expires" in all of our Salesforce Profiles in order to prevent our users from being prompted to reset their (now unused) Salesforce passwords in the future when they have expired ?

Thank you.

Comment: Out of the box, the prompt to change an expired password only happens when you use the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, passwords expire. If the password is expired, SSO will still work normally. They will not be forced to change their password until they log in with their Salesforce password, as opposed to their SSO authentication.

Comment: Would it not be the case that they cannot login using the Salesforce password, since SSO is enabled and Salesforce will always leverage the external authenticator? I.e. whether the Salesforce password expires is moot since it is not and cannot be used (unless SSO is subsequently removed)?

Comment: I guess that depends on the answer to [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/368040/50252) too... interesting.

Comment: @PhilW an SSO enabled user still has a Salesforce password, and users with SSO can still theoretically log in with their password, if they know it. With Delegated Authentication, Salesforce users an external server to validate passwords.

Comment: @sfdcfox - So they will be allowed to login by using the SSO link even if their SF password has expired ?

Comment: @Zoom_v Yes, using any form of SSO bypasses the expired password check. It's not until you use a Salesforce password that you'll be forced to change it (e.g. UI login or SOAP API call).